# Read multi variable csv bash build multi line file from it

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I had what I thought was a simple concept which I could easily do as I did something similar.

I have an input file input.csv

```
1a,1b
2a,2b
```

I would like the following output

Output file 1

```
This is variable 1 named 1a ok
This is variable 2 named 1b ok
```

Output file 2

```
This is variable 1 named 2a ok
This is variable 2 named 2b ok
```

I thought I could do something similar to below

```
i=1
while IFS=, read var1 var2; do
echo This is variable 1 named "var1" > filenamei
echo This is variable 2 named "var2" >> filenamei
i=i+1
done </inputfile.csv
```

I previously wrote code to take a single variable from a long file and write output to a single file and it worked fine.  Like below

Input file

```
a
b
```

Single output file

```
This is A
This is B
```

Script was

```
while read p;do
echo this is "$p" >>output file
done < input file
```

Been through lots of different errors but getting nowhere.

Comment: Are there really blanks in the input file? Or is it `1a,1b` etc., without blanks?

Comment: No blanks in this example. Final version will include a timestam thoug

Comment: for each iteration the file is truncated `>`, whereas `>>` appends, redirection may be moved out of the loop

Comment: But your example input does show blanks. Is it incorrect?

Comment: input file corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easy by configuring double loop: the outer loop to iterate over lines and the inner one for comma-separated fields. Then how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while read -r line; do
    ifs_back="$IFS"
    IFS=","
    set -- $line
    for ((j=1; j<=$#; j++)); do
        echo This is variable "$j" named "${!j}" >> "filename${i}"
    done
    IFS="$ifs_back"
    i=$((i+1))
done < "inputfile.csv"
```

**Explanations:**

- In order to split the input line with commas, we temporarily set `IFS` to "," then assign the fields to positional parameters `$1`, `$2`.
- The loop counter `j` for the inner loop starts with 1 and ends with `$#1`, number of fields.
- We can access the value of the positional parameter via `${!j}`.
- As a clean up of the inner loop, we retrieve `IFS` and increment `i` for the next line.

The code above is flexible with #lines and #fields so would work with the input:

```
1a,1b
2a,2b
3a,3b
```

as wel as with:

```
1a,1b,1c
2a,2b,2c
3a,3b,3c
```

Hope this helps.